# Concurrent Threads graph is showing 0 in JMeter bzm - Concurrency Thread Group while using tstFeedback function

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am new to JMeter. I have a test plan with the 'Concurrency thread group' along with 'Throughput Shaping Timer'. In the 'Target Concurrency' field of the 'Concurrency thread group', I am using the schedule feedback function to maintain thread count required. However, the 'concurrent threads' graph is not showing as per the value mentioned in the feedback function instead, it is showing 0. How to fix this so, the graph reflects the threads mentioned in the feedback function? I have given the screenshot of my thread group [concurrent thread group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOn75.png)

Answer (score 0):

Given you integrate [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) with the [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-throughput-shaping-timer-plugin/) the chart with anticipated concurrency can be observer in the **Throughput Shaping Timer** as the function cannot be evaluated while your script is not running.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I can see the graph in the Timer screen. However, when I run the test, the __tstFeedback function is not spinning up any active threads at any time(as the graph is always a flatline in thread group screen), so no request is sent to the API and there is no output in the listeners. I think for some reason, the __tstFeedback function is not working for me. Could it be anything to do with the Throughput Shaping Timer plugin not being enabled properly or issue with the integration to the Thread Group? Would you kindly help with this, please?

Comment: We need to see the full screenshot of your test plan, screenshot of the throughput shaping timer and [jmeter.log](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging/) file in order to be able to provide further assistance.

Comment: Hi, Please find the images of test plan & throughput shaping timer in the following links: https://imgur.com/PZrNXaC, https://imgur.com/FBSVvWn. I am still checking a way to send the jmeter.log file as the comment section doesn't allow to attach files.

Comment: Hi, Please find my Jmeter.log file in the following link: https://pastebin.com/Kz7rMwSR

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this. I downloaded the Throughput Shaping Timer [plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/?search=jpgc-tst) from the JMeter plugins website and added it into my JMeter installation directory: /usr/local/Cellar/jmeter/⁨5.2.1⁩/⁨libexec⁩/lib⁩. And a restart to the JMeter fixed it. Now, the __tstFeedback function is supplying the concurrent threads dynamically.